# How to check if the line i of a dataframe is equal to a value?

Tags: python, dataframe

I can't manage to resolve this problem.

```
for i in range(0,len(df1.columns)):
    if df1.iloc[i:].values ==1:
        print ('Buy')
        order= True
    elif df1.iloc[i:] == -1:
        print ('Sell')
        order= True
    else:
        print ('Do nothing')
        time.sleep(30)
    if a==5:
        break
```

I have a `dataframe` `df1` which includes values -1, 0 and 1. 
So basically i'm trying to print for example "buy" if the value 1 appears in the dataframe (this code is the end of a loop, before that I'm setting every 30s a new value for `df`)

To resume:

Set a new value for df every 30s (already did that)
check if this value is -1,0 or 1
print every 30s 'buy' 'sell' or 'Do nothing' according the new value, time sleep and then set a new value for `df` etc.

When I run the code above, it gave me: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Providing a sample of what `df1` looks like will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you tried to compare a list with a single value, you got this error message

your data frame df1 shape is not clear to us, so i'm guessing here, try to change

```
if df1.iloc[i:].values ==1:
```

to

```
if df1.iloc[i] ==1:
```

and also change

```
elif df1.iloc[i:] == -1:
```

to

```
elif df1.iloc[i] == -1:
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for your answer. I already tried this, its keeps telling me the same ValueError "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous", maybe because the output of this is True or False so a bool type ? (df1 is a dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Martineau thanks for your answer.

Filter means that the signal is 'buy' if its 1, 'Sell' if its -1, 'do nothing' if 0.
Lag is just to capture change in the signal, and finally strat = filter*lag.

So, with my strat columns, I take my position only once, and if the signal stay at the same position, it will give 0 (do nothing).

My problem is that I want after every loop 'round' check if the last value of the dataframe is -1,1 or 0. Its seems that the output is a bool value..

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vMTT.png) 
[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vegti.png)